# Injective + closed range imply boundedly invertible on range?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $L$ be some operator.

Suppose $L$ is injective and has closed range: Does this imply that $L$ is boundedly invertible on the Range?

Comment: Do you have tried anything?

Comment: I think that invertible on the range is clear, since if $y\in rg(L)$, i.e. $y=Lx$ for some $x$ in the domain of $L$ and $L$ is injective, i.e. there is no other element in the pre-image of $\{y\}$, we have that $L^{-1}y=x$. If I am not terribly mistaken. But boundedness is more difficult.

Comment: Is $L$ defined on a Banach space?

Comment: I think so, yes

Comment: Is $L$ bounded?

Comment: I only know that $\lVert Lu\rVert\to 0$ so I guess it is bounded.

Comment: Sloppy, sloppy, sloppy,..... What do you mean when you say $\lVert Lu\rVert\to 0$ ????

Comment: I am sorry for being so sloppy. The problem is that this is from a very rough blackboard comment and I do not know the details. All what is said that we have that $L$ has bounded inverse on its range and that this contradicts $\frac{\lVert u\rVert}{\rVert Lu\rVert}\to +\infty$ what was shown very sloppy before. Maybe you can see why this gives a contradiction, I cannot.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is formulated very sloppy !!

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $L:X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator.

If $L(X)$ is closed, then $L(X) $ is a Banach space. If $L$ is also injective, then $L^{-1}:L(X) \to X$ is bounded.

This is a consequence of the open mapping theorem.